# Two different parenthesis syntax in return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following this tutorial on getting started in ReactJS at https://scotch.io/tutorials/learning-react-getting-started-and-concepts and came across this general code, which has two different parenthesis for return statement.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        count: 5
    }
},
render: function(){
    return (
        <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
    )
}
});
```

Why are they different? Swapping either one of them results an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is a valid JS return of an object, the second is a grouping operator. Using `(stuff && moreStuff)` in a return statement will return the **result** of the code inside the parenthesis, whatever that may be.

In this case there is some special JSX inside the parenthesis which a browser does not understand. This is converted before it's executed, usually at compile time, to a nested tree of `react.createElement(...)` calls. The JSX is just for convenience to give you an HTML-like experience.

As I said parenthesis just returns the result of what is inside, so you could for example return an object inside it, which is useful when writing short arrow functions: `const mergeObject = (obj1, obj2) => ({ ...obj1, ...obj2 })` instead of:

```
const mergeObject = (obj1, obj2) => {
  return {
    ...obj1,
    ...obj2,
  };
}
```

Comment: Not really, the parenthesis is not required in order to return JSX. It's normal JavaScript grouping operator which is used so that you can have JSX below your `return` keyword and multiline returns.

Comment: @limelights true, though it's an invalid grouping operator without jsx

Comment: @DominicTobias thanks for the answer. Does React pass this off to JSX transformers?

Comment: @dangdis only if you pass it through a compiler, the standard way these days is to use webpack + babel to compile your code (you can use watch mode). The JSX transformer FB developed has been discontinued because babel is better. There is a JSX library by facebook which will do it on the fly but it's not intended for production (http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.0.js)